# Synchronous MySQL query with NodeJS and KnexJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, knex.js

I'm new with NodeJs so I'm stuck with its async behavior, in particular with queries to a MySQL database based on the KnexJS module

Here is the function with the queries:

```
var getNotes = function(owner) {
        if(owner !== undefined) {
            knex.table('tblnotes').where('public',1).orWhere({ownerName : owner}).select('noteId').then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                return result;
            });
        }
        else {
            knex.table('tblnotes').where('public',1).select('noteId').then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                return result;
            });
        }
}
```

But when I use it

```
var query = getNotes(user.username);
console.log("authenticated");
console.log(query);
console.log("--------------------------------------");
return res.render('authindex.ejs', {title : "Index", user : user,data : query});
```

and I log the result I have:

```
authenticated
undefined
--------------------------------------
[ { noteId: 1 } ]
```

Comment: use callbacks for synchronous behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**: Use callbacks

```
var getNotes = function(owner, callback) {
    if(owner !== undefined) {
        knex.table('tblnotes').where('public',1).orWhere({ownerName : owner}).select('noteId').then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            callback(result);
        });
    }
    else {
        knex.table('tblnotes').where('public',1).select('noteId').then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            callback(result);
        });
    }
}
```

And use it in routes as following

```
getNotes(user.username, function(result){
   console.log("authenticated");
   console.log(result);
   console.log("--------------------------------------");
   return res.render('authindex.ejs', {title : "Index", user : user,data : result});
});
```

**Solution 2**: Use promises

```
var getNotes = function(owner) {
    if(owner !== undefined) {
        return knex.table('tblnotes').where('public',1).orWhere({ownerName : owner}).select('noteId');
    }
    else {
        return knex.table('tblnotes').where('public',1).select('noteId');
    }
}
```

And use it in routes as following:

```
getNotes(user.username).then(function(result){
   console.log("authenticated");
   console.log(result);
   console.log("--------------------------------------");
   return res.render('authindex.ejs', {title : "Index", user : user,data : result});
});
```